# Magento - MySQL - SQL rules are NOT working for new Extension

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on a new extension for Magento 1.9.0.1.

Let me give you some information.

I have fully disabled the Cache system.

When i developed the extension i've created the MySQL table via phpmyadmin. When i finished and packed it i tried to install it on another Magento, then i noticed that the MySQL table is not created with the installation.

Note that i did not received any errors.

Here is what i have in my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource</resourceModel>
        </smsnotification>
        <vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
        <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <smsnotification>
            <table>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</table>
            </smsnotification>
            <smsnotificationhistory>
            <table>VivasIndustries_SmsHistory</table>
            </smsnotificationhistory>
        </entities>
        </vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <smsnotification_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                 <use>core_setup</use>
             </connection>
        </smsnotification_setup>
        <smsnotification_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_read>
        <smsnotification_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_write>
    </resources>    
    <events>
    <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after_smsprice_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>smsnotification/newordertotalobserver</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>saveSmspriceTotal</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after_smsprice_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>  
    <checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_single> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>     
          <checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_single_smsprice_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>smsnotification/newordertotalobserver</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>saveSmspriceTotalForMultishipping</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_single_smsprice_handler>      
        </observers>
      </checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_single>     
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
                    <class>smsnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>orderSaved</method>
                </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
     <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>                
                <smsprice_total>
                    <class>smsnotification/quote_address_total_smsprice</class>
                    <after>subtotal,freeshipping,tax_subtotal,shipping</after>
                    <before>grand_total</before>
                </smsprice_total> 
            </totals>
        </quote>
            <order_invoice>
                <totals>                
                <smsprice_total>
                    <class>smsnotification/order_invoice_total_smsprice</class>
                    <after>subtotal,freeshipping,tax_subtotal,shipping</after>
                    <before>grand_total</before>
                </smsprice_total> 
                </totals>
            </order_invoice>
            <order_creditmemo>
                <totals>                
                <smsprice_total>
                    <class>percentpayment/order_creditmemo_total_smsprice</class>
                    <after>subtotal,freeshipping,tax_subtotal,shipping</after>
                    <before>grand_total</before>
                </smsprice_total> 
                </totals>
            </order_creditmemo>
    </sales>    
    <helpers>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <smsnotification>
             <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <vivas>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </vivas>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <smsnotification>
                <file>smsnotification.xml</file>
            </smsnotification>
        </updates>
    </layout>   
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <default>
    <vivas>
        <smspricegroup>                
            <smsprice_name>SMS Notification</smsprice_name>
            <smsprice_fee>0.5</smsprice_fee>            
        </smspricegroup>      
    </vivas>
    </default>
</config>
```

Here is what i have in: `/app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/sql/smsnotification_setup/install-1.0.0.php`:

```
<?php
$installer=$this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("quote_address", "smsprice_total", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("order", "smsprice_total", array("type"=>"varchar"));

$installer->run("
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `smstext` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `VivasIndustries_SmsHistory` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `receiver` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `smstext` text NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

    ");
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

It is not creating the table even if do not run both addAttributes

So guys why this extension is not creating the MySQL table and how can i fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: You dont need KEY on the same column you have a PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Please if you are sure that this is the problem make an answer with your suggestion. Also i have to say that `$installer->addAttribute("quote_address", "smsprice_total", array("type"=>"varchar"));` is not working either!

Comment: Strangely mysql allows it, just tested it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb The problem might be in that the run function cant execute 2 statements or more at the same time.Try to run it twice for each table

Comment: It is not creating the table even if do not run both `addAttribute`s

Comment: Put the details in the question comments are hard to read

Comment: Can you be more specific of what you do not understand ?

Comment: I think @Mihai means that it is better to update the question with clarifications and improvements by editing it, so that new readers do not need to wade through various updates to understand the current state of the question. `:-)` Admittedly this question only has a few, but nevertheless merging comments into questions is a frequent request on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

First off: Put a die in your install file and see if it gets there.
To further debug see if any entries are created/have been created in core_resource for `smsnotification_setup` and if so delete them to re-run the setup.

Secondary and for the love of simplicity don't camel-case your module names to avoid much pain and suffering.

Here's a installer prototype non-camel-cased:

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vivasindustries_Smsnotification>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Vivasindustries_Smsnotification>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <smsnotification_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Vivasindustries_Smsnotification</module>
                    <class>Vivasindustries_Smsnotification_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </smsnotification_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Installer: `sql/smsnotification_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php`

```
// die( 'In install!' );
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...
    ");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: I don't get your advice about the `First off: Put a die in your install file and see if it gets there.` Can you please show me with example in your answer ?

Comment: Also you are pointing a name of the files as `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` when the current version of the extension is `1.0.0`. Does it have to be `mysql4-install-1.0.0.php` or i am in wrong ? Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely. Typo on my part. The die is to ensure that it gets to the install file. die( 'in installer' ); at the very top of php inside the installer.

Comment: So i just have to uncomment `die( 'In install!' );` at the top of the `mysql4-install-1.0.0.php` and if there is some problem it will yell it or it will yell it if it runs so i'll be sure that this installer file is executed ?

Comment: Just a test to see if config.xml is configured properly and your core_resource having the correct installer data.